# Can someone explain me what metadata is in plain simple terms from the perspective of SalesForce

Tags: metadata, trailhead

Can someone please explain me in plain simple English.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_admin_beginner/modules/starting_force_com/units/starting_understanding_arch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, objects, fields and any other configurable things (setup information) can be considered as metadata.

Metadata can be the Configurable objects say Account, Contact, Lead and any other custom objects. The attributes of those objects defined by Fields.

So, you can say, it's a structure or template for creating the records (i.e. data).

Like.

`Lead` object has attributes as fields.

- First Name
- Last Name
- Company
- Email

Based on the metadata, we create the data i.e. the records.

For example, `Lead` record can be created based on those attributes like

- First Name - 'John'
- Last Name - 'Smith'
- Company - 'XYZ'
- Email - 'JS@xyz.com'

All the elements which we need to configure and customize in our org is metadata.